# Function argument for all values in R (raster extract, and velox raster extract)

Tags: r

I'm using the package velox to speed up raster extraction.

Simple question (and probably an easy one): what is the argument in R for fun=all values?

Context:
In the raster package the function extract fun=NULL is to return all pixel values. In velox the extract requires an argument "fun=". What is the function argument that will return all the cell values like the fun=NULL of the extract in the raster package?

Bonus points if you have a function that will take the mean while ignoring NA values (which is what I'm trying to do anyhow). Something along the lines of

```
meanvalue <- raster::extract(testraster, testpoly, fun=mean if x !=NA)
```

Id then use it on a velox raster (should work the same) like this rather than the above code:

```
meanvalue <- velox.testraster$extract(testpoly, fun=mean if x !=NA)
```

Fun=mean doesn't work because some of my polygons have NA values for pixels since they are not covered by the raster.

Comment: values() for all values. Watch out the return types is matrix for brick/stack

Comment: in the velox code fun=values, fun=values(), fun=val, gives me the error Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘values’ for signature ‘"missing"’. I guess a better question would be how to get every output of the extraction, missing or values. Seems the issue may not be with values but the fact it's trying to return values that don't exist.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't paying enough attention, will try to explore properly and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
fun <- function(x){mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)})
```

for `velox`:

```
sample.list <- sampleVeloxraster$extract(sampleshp, fun=function(x){mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)})
```